# Update php stripe integration to work with stripe.js V3 Strong Customer Authentication

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to up grade a site so that its stripe integration will work with Strong Customer Authentication (SCA). From what I have read stripe.js version 3 will handle this and will have to change my payment from markup.

What I confused about is what version of the stripe PHP library I should use, If I'm making changes it makes sense to grab the latest version of the stripe php library as the version I have dates from sometime in 2017.

If I look on the VERSION file in the stripe folder in my site it says its version 6.6.0 but on GitHub the latest version is is 6.37.0 (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/VERSION)

Why is my version number higher than what should be the latest version on GitHub?

Do I need to change my PHP stripe library to work with stripe.js version 3?

Comment: If you want to build an integration with Payment Intents (SCA compliant payment flow using Stripe.js v3), I'd recommend upgrading your `stripe-php` to the latest. Looking at the Changelog (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) support for Payment Intents was added in the PHP library in 6.9.0, but other resources since then.  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents

Comment: I am such a dumby!
I 6.6.6 but I was seeing the new version that is 6.37.0 as being older because of the 3 I did not see it as bring 37! If was not for posting the link to the change log I would of not of worked that out. Thanks for unintentionally pointing out the Obvious. ;-)